# How can I mine bitcoin faster?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, bitcoinj

I'm curios what kind of PC, I need to mine bitcoins. What OS system, what GPU, CPU, etc...

my current specification are:
CPU: Xeon e3-1230v3
GPU: GTX 780
RAM: 24gb
OS: Windows 8.1(64bits)

So what do u think about that spec, and what do u think i can change for faster mining?

Answer (score 2):

For Bitcoin mining, you need a Bitcoin miner, not a PC.